# Codeigniter get variable (with post value) from another function in one class

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

Here is my scenario. I have a form with date input that I use as a variable input in my model.

Here is my view for displaying form `v_soaotc_daily_index.php`

```
<form class="form_horizontal" method = "post" action="<?php echo site_url('soaotc/getDaily');?>">
     <fieldset> 
         <!-- Date Input name="date_daily" -->
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

The form is processed in controller `getDaily()`

```
function getDaily(){
        $date_daily = $this->input->post('date_daily');
        $data=array(
            'title'=>'SOA_OTC - Daily',
            'active_otc'=>'active',
            'day'=>$this->model_app->get_Soa_Daily($date_daily)
        );

        $this->load->view('element/v_header',$data);
        $this->load->view('pages/v_soaotc_daily');
        $this->load->view('element/v_footer');
    }
```

`$day` will return an array that i will display as a chart using highchart. So i encode json for this array in another function and use POST variable from getDaily()

```
function daily_json(){
        $this->getDaily(); <!-- connecting to getDaily() -->

        $data=array(
            'day'=>$this->model_app->get_Soa_Daily($date_daily)
        ); 
            .
            .
            .
         blablabla
            .
            .
            .

        echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

I `print_r($day)` in view and the result is ok. But the chart can't display because there is no JSON returned from `daily_json()`. Kindly help me for this. Thank you

Comment: update question with `var_dump($this->input->post('date_daily'))` and post model function `get_Soa_Daily`

Comment: Where do you define `$result`? Shouldn't that be `$data`?

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, you should return the `JSON` value and then print it.

But, you are printing it:

`echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Change it to:

`return json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

And in view, `echo` it.

Comment: Do i write the correct code for calling variable from another function?